# Is there a way to authenticate gspread with the default service account?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, gspread

If I want to create/read/update spreadsheets using `gspread`, I know first have to authenticate like so:

```py
import gspread

gc = gspread.service_account()
```

Where I can also specify the filename to point to a service account json key, but is there a way I can tell `gspread` to **use the default service account credentials without pointing to a json?**

My use-case is that I want to run `gspread` in a vm (or cloud function) that already comes with an IAM role and I can't seem to figure out where to get the json file from. I also don't want to copy the json to the vm unnecessarily.

Comment: I am not sure about Google Sheets, but usually Google Client libraries will use the service account assigned to a Google Service automatically. Research ADC (Application Default Credentials). However, remember that a service account is an identity, so interacting with Google Sheets will require  an account setup under the service account's identity unless you are using impersonation (Domain Wide Delegation).

Comment: Yes, I'm using those default creds for gcs, firestore etc. without any issues, but gspread is acting up and  the docs seem to say the only way to auth is via service account json.

Comment: The statement "acting up" is not helpful. Show your code (not a tidbit), the request, the response and errors. If you mention docs, include the link and the text you are referencing.

Answer (score 3):

You can use google.auth to get the credentials of the default service account.
Then you can use gspread.authorize() with these credentials:

```
import google.auth
import gspread

credentials, project_id = google.auth.default(
    scopes=[
        'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
    ]
)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the use case, Cloud function has [Runtime](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity#runtime_service_account) service account feature which allows you to use default service account or you can attach any service account to the cloud function.

Using this [library](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.auth.html) you can do the thing without json file.

```
import google.auth

credentials, project_id = google.auth.default()
```

Comment: That didn't work. Even thought I set the scopes and enabled drive and spreadsheets apis in the project. I also tried compute_engine.Credentials without any luck.

Comment: I also jumped on this issue to ask the devs: https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/820

Comment: I might be wrong. You need to create json key file. However, in the same cloud function you can generate this key file based on the service account using [python-code](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating_service_account_keys). Then use this key file name on 

creds, _ = google.auth.default('secret.json',scopes=DEFAULT_SCOPES)

Comment: Ever found a solution to this @niczky12 ?

Comment: Works on Cloud functions but on compute engine or kubernetes :|